# What is the purpose of bitshifting by 0

Tags: c, linux, driver, gpu, performance-testing

I am reviewing the open source AMD GPU drivers for Linux. I noticed something I haven't seen before, and I would like to know the purpose. On line 1441 of the sid.h file, there are a series of defines that are integers being bitshifted left by 0. Wouldn't this just result in the original integer being operated on?

Here is an excerpt and a link to the head

```
    #define VGT_EVENT_INITIATOR                      0xA2A4
    #define SAMPLE_STREAMOUTSTATS1                   (1 << 0)
    #define SAMPLE_STREAMOUTSTATS2                   (2 << 0)
    #define SAMPLE_STREAMOUTSTATS3                   (3 << 0)
```

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/sid.h#L1441

Also, I am learning to access the performance counter registers of AMD GPUs in order to calculate the GPU load. Any tips on that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: This is probably generated automatically by some kind of macro. It might have a bit-shifted version for use in bitfield-type values as well as an enum-type version.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out that it is just a bug in how the code was written. I'm pretty well versed in this sort of thing and I can't think of a good reason to write this. It could fall out of a badly written automatic code generator, but even that is fairly sloppy.

Comment: @Zalman Stern: Nope. If this is intended for placing an integer value into a manually impemented bit-field at bit-offset `0`, then shift by `0` is a very good programming practice. I'd go as far as state that this is *required* in any self-respecting code.

Comment: Ok, I can see that, though in that case, I'd probably go ahead and mask it with the bitfield mask as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Things like that could be done just for the sake of consistency (not necessarily applicable to your specific case). For example, I can describe a set of single-bit flags as

```
#define FLAG_1 0x01
#define FLAG_2 0x02
#define FLAG_3 0x04
#define FLAG_4 0x08
```

or as

```
#define FLAG_1 (1u << 0)
#define FLAG_2 (1u << 1)
#define FLAG_3 (1u << 2)
#define FLAG_4 (1u << 3)
```

In the first line of the latter approach I did not have to shift by `0`. But it just looks more consistent that way and emphasizes the fact that `FLAG_1` has the same nature as the rest of the flags. And `0` acts as a placeholder for a different value, if I some day decide to change it.

You can actually see exactly that in the linked code with shift by `0` in the definitions of `DYN_OR_EN` and `DYN_RR_EN` macros.

---

The approach can be extended to multi-bit fields within a word, like in the following (contrived) example

```
// Bits 0-3 - lower counter, bits 4-7 - upper counter

#define LOWER_0  (0u << 0)
#define LOWER_1  (1u << 0)
#define LOWER_2  (2u << 0)
#define LOWER_3  (3u << 0)

#define UPPER_0  (0u << 4)
#define UPPER_1  (1u << 4)
#define UPPER_2  (2u << 4)
#define UPPER_3  (3u << 4)

unsigned packed_counters = LOWER_2 + UPPER_3; /* or `LOWER_2 | UPPER_3` */
```

Again, shifts by `0` bits are present purely for visual consistency. As well as shifts of `0` values.

You can actually see exactly that in the linked code with shift by `0` in the definitions of `LC_XMIT_N_FTS` and `LC_XMIT_N_FTS_MASK` macros.

Comment: The values given are linearly consecutive, not powers of two so the usage is just very confusing. Making conceptually different things -- single bit flags vs. a linear enumeration -- visually consistent is not helpful.

Comment: @Zalman Stern: This could simply mean that these values are intended for placement onto a multi-bit bit-field located at offset `0` in the containing word. See the extra example above.

Comment: I usually shift by 0 for this reason .. surely the compiler just optimizes it out.

Comment: Good use of `u` in forming the shift values.

Comment: Answer is much better after addition of context on bitfields. Once again, the original header should document that and such if this is the use. Really though, I cannot recall having seen this *ever* in a vast experience of programming. I've seen techniques that use a single macro to put the value into a bitfield and I've seen using a named constant for the shift offset. (Where the value of one of the shift constants might be zero.)

Comment: Even more it is the constant value which is evaluated the compile time and those "shifts" will not appear in the compiled code \.